# Getting hebrew json to php file

Tags: php, json, encoding, hebrew

I'm trying to parse this json file in php: http://www.oref.org.il/WarningMessages/alerts.json

This file contains Hebrew letters which cause encoding problems.

My script:

```
$content = file_get_contents('http://www.oref.org.il/WarningMessages/alerts.json'); 
$json = json_decode($content);
echo $json->id;
```

It just won't display anything. I just get a blank page. But if I do `echo $content;` it shows the json file perfectly.

Json file example:

```
{ 
"id" : "1434292591050",
"title" : "פיקוד העורף התרעה  באזור ",
"data" : []
}
```

I've been reading few other similar problems and solutions but none of them helped fixing this problem. I've been trying to use `mb_detect_encoding` and `iconv` but it didn't help.

Thank you!

Comment: Show, how did you try to use `iconv`? What is the script encoding?

Comment: @umka `$content = iconv("ISO-8859-8", "UTF-8", hebrev(iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-8", $content)));` It shows a blank page. I don't think iconv can solve the probelm, but I gave it as an example for something I've tried. The script encoding is UTF-8.

Comment: What do you get if you do `var_dump($json);` ?

Comment: @Elin I just get `NULL`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file content you're getting is in UTF-16 charset. You have to convert it:

```
$content = file_get_contents('http://www.oref.org.il/WarningMessages/alerts.json'); 
$content=iconv("UTF-16", "UTF-8", $content);
$json = json_decode($content,true);
print_r($json);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I've been trying to fix it over 2 hours already!

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following `iconv`:

```
$content = iconv('utf-16', 'utf-8', $content);
```

then `json_decode` works properly and returns:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [id] => 1434292591050
    [title] => פיקוד העורף התרעה  באזור 
    [data] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

Comment: Thank you, but sorry umka answered first, but you answer is good :)
Do you know how do I get the data from the array?

Comment: @MorHaviv Actually, I was first with several seconds ahead :). Anyway, about the array, I guess that you are talking about the `data` element. You will be able to get it in the same way you can get the other elements (as you do with `id` already) - `$array = $json->data;`. Note that you have to use `json_decode($content);`. Specifying the `true` flag at the end returns associative array and not `stdClass` and in this case you can not refer objects with `->` notation.

Comment: Thank you for your advice but for some reason it's not working.this is my script:  `$content = file_get_contents('http://www.klh-dev.com/cumta/systems/testszone/alerts.json'); 
 $content=iconv("UTF-16", "UTF-8", $content);
 $json = json_decode($content);

 $cityArray = array(
  'id' =>  "'" . $json['id'] . "'",
  'title' =>  "'" . $json['title'] . "'",
  'areas' => "'" . $json->data . "'",
 );`

Comment: @MorHaviv You are mixing the two formats. You have to set `true` for `json_decode` and also, `$json->data` will be `$json['data']`. Also, I am not sure why you want to enclose everything in quotes, but this would definitely not work for `data`. So, I would do it as follows: `$json = json_decode($content); $cityArray = array( 'id' => $json->id, 'title' => $json->title, 'areas' => $json->data ); print_r($cityArray);`. You can check http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php for some info about how `json_decode` should be used.

Comment: @MorHaviv Also, it makes little sense to make an exact copy of the `$json` associative array.